# SQL query to remove duplicates of multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have database 'prices' with 1 million of rows.

it is made of 3 columns:
price
timeframe
timestamp

I want to remove all the rows that have the same `timeframe` AND `timestamp`, BUT keeping one row.

Example:

```
price  timeframe  timestamp
14     60         1508407200
1.6    60         1508407200
26     90         1508407200
```

After running the query, I will get:

```
price  timeframe  timestamp
14     60         1508407200
26     90         1508407200
```

What MySql query would you use to do that?

Comment: You want the lowest price in a group of same `timeframe` and `timestamp`, the first one, or a random pick?

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest aggregation

```
select max(price) as price, timeframe, timestamp
from prices
group by timeframe, timestamp;
```

If you always know that the prices are unique for a give `timeframe`/`timestamp` combo, you can instead do:

```
select p.*
from prices p
where p.price = (select max(p2.price) from prices p2 where p2.timeframe = p.timeframe and p2.timestamp = p.timestamp);
```

This has the advantage that you an readily get other columns on the same row.